# Run jQuery on Blaze template DOM

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

Per [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) I should be able to run jQuery in the onRendered event of a template.

I'm trying the following:

**client.html**

```
<body style="padding:10px;">
  {{> controls}}
</body>

<template name="controls">
  {{#each network}}
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    {{#each (device this)}}
      {{name}}
      <input data-slider-min="100" data-slider-max="-0.01" data-slider-step="1">
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**client.js**

```
Template.controls.helpers({
  'network': function(){
    return networks.find()
  },
  'device': function(network){
    return network.devices()
  }
});

Template.controls.onRendered(function(){
  this.$('input').slider();
});
```

As a test, I also changed the onRendered function to run the following which worked correctly:

```
Template.controls.onRendered(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){this.$('input').slider()}, 120)
});
```

This is hacky and ugly though, I'd much rather have it trigger off a callback so I know it's happening at the right time and that no other conditions that may cause unexpected delays stop it from working.

What do I need to change in order to have the jQuery run after the DOM nodes are rendered and ready to act on?

Comment: You could abstract your `input` into a new template (just the insides of the loop not the actual loop) and run your code in the `onRendered` callback of this new template

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use template level subscriptions and apply the sliders when the subscription is ready.
Assuming your publication is called something like 'networkdata':

```
Template.controls.onRendered(function(){
    this.autorun(function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('networkdata', {
            onReady: function () {
                this.$('.sliders').slider();
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }.bind(this));
});
```

I used .sliders class selector but you could use any valid jquery selector.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go later. Does this fire multiple times for if the data is updated after the initial load?

Comment: No, it will not fire when data is updated. That is, the sliders will be created only once. When data is updated your template is updated of course (network.name and device.name).

Comment: It didn't, I'm still seeing the same delay and it still works if I wrap it in setTimeout. I've moved on to using a different slider instead that's got no jQuery components and it's working well.